# UITextView not Responding to Touch Events after Animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, animation, uitextview

I am performing an animation to correctly keep the `UITextView` at the bottom of the screen if I expand the view. For some reason if I perform the animation, the `UITextView` stop responding to touch events, so there is no keyboard that will show up.

All I am doing is:

```
CGRect newSendTextView = self.commTextView.frame;
newSendTextView.origin.y = (newSendTextView.origin.y + (height - self.defaultSize.size.height));

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
self.commTextView.frame = newSendTextView;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I know the `UITextView` is still on the screen after I do the transformation since I colored the `UITextView` background a bright blue, but it doesn't want to respond to any touch events.

If I comment out `self.commTextView.frame = newSendTextView;` so that it doesn't move, the touch events register.

I have no idea why this happens, I tried

```
[self.commTextView becomeFirstRespond];
```

and I have checked if `isEditable` and `isUserInteractionEnabled` is set to `1` and it is.

Comment: do you have any object in the front of your UITextView? maybe you have  a transparent UIView, in this case you cannot access it

Comment: @MouhamadLamaa No, I checked. There is no transparent view and in the IB TextView is at the front of every item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, new position of `TextView` might be getting overlayed by other view. Check any other `View` is having same frame on your `TextView` new position. Use `clipsToBounds` property to find it.

Comment: Your answer helped me figure it out. It seems that I did not stretch the UIView that contains these view so they weren't responding to touch events. I did not know that if a view is outside of its superview that it would still show up on the screen... Thanks Arthan

Comment: @Alan : how did you solved  this error? I also have similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993151/after-using-cgaffinetransform-action-on-viewable-uibutton-is-not-called

Comment: @FahimParker basically the textview was outside of the view that contains its. For example if you add the textview into a view that is of (0,0, 100, 100). If I tell the textview to go to (150, 150, 100, 100), it will still show up on the screen because it's within the bounds of the iPhone screen. However, if the textview is not within the bounds of the UIView that it was added to, it will not respond to touch events. Basically all I did was resize its parent view so the UITextview always remains within the bounds.