# UIButton not responding after animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction, cgaffinetransform

**I would prefer first download the project from below link and then continue with question** (only 36kb)

[**Download Link**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8v8wxzci3jpcei/TopMenu.zip)

At start what I have is like below.

[image]

When I click My Office button, I am calling action `actionSeenButton` which will print `NSLog(@"actionSeenButton");`

```
- (IBAction)actionSeenButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"actionSeenButton");
}
```

This works perfect.

When I click, Show hidden button, I am sliding view by 100 and showing the image and buttons that I have at the top, as shown in below image

[image]

Code used is

```
- (IBAction)showHiddenButton:(id)sender {
    CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 100);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    self.view.transform = translation;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

When I click this button, I am calling action `actionHiddenButton` which will print `NSLog(@"actionHiddenButton");`

```
- (IBAction)actionHiddenButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"actionHiddenButton");
}
```

**BUT the problem is, when I click the new button that I see, action is not getting called.**

Any idea why this is happening?

---

### Note

When I move the top hidden button from y=-70 to y=170, action is getting called.

Sample project can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8v8wxzci3jpcei/TopMenu.zip)

***What I wanted to implement is, showing three buttons (as menu) on the top in one line by moving view down.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yipeee!!! Below is how I did.

### .h

Added new variable.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *hideStatus;
```

### .m

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
    CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -100);
    self.view.transform = translation;
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-80,320,560);
    hideStatus = @"hidden";
}

- (IBAction)showHiddenButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"hideStatus===%@", hideStatus);
    CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    if ([hideStatus isEqualToString:@"hidden"]) {
        translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
        hideStatus = @"shown";
    } else {
        translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -100);
        hideStatus = @"hidden";
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    self.view.transform = translation;
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Attached is the sample project. You can download from [**here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqnpneqgdzr2yeq/TopMenu_Updated.zip).

Comment: instead of having a @"hidden" string, why not just use a BOOL? that is their intended purpose. so you could have "@property (assign) BOOL isHidden;" then in your if statement you would either have "if(isHidden)..." or "if(!isHidden)...". also this "CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;" is unnecessary. it should just be "CGAffineTransform translation;". since you are reusing it in different methods you might as well make it a property.

Comment: @DoS : crap.. I know I could have used boolean, but I have not used for some reason... I have more status for hide and for that reason I am using string.. I have many status and based on status I am going to show/hide the required content... Though, thanks for ur help

Answer (score 1):

verify that your button is not behind the frame of another view. even if the button is visable, if there is something covering it up it wont work. i don't have access to xcode at the moment but my guess is your view "stack" is prohibiting you from interacting with the button. a button is esentually a uiview and you can do all the same animations to buttons and labels that you can with views. your best bet is to leave the view in the background alone and just move your buttons. since your "hidden" button isn't part of your main "view" hiarchy thats where your problem is.

upon further investigation, your problem is related to auto-layout and making sure your button object stays in the view hierarchy. if you turn off auto-layout you will see where the problem is. when you animate the main view down the "hidden" button is off of the view and there for inactive. the easiest solution is to just animate the buttons. the next best solution closest to what you have is to add another view onto your "main view" and then put the buttons into that view. also why do you have that background image twice? why not just set the background color of your view to that same yellow?

Comment: **the easiest solution is to just animate the buttons.** ***is tough because, it will be tough for me doing this for all viewcontroller.***

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your project and it seems the translation you're making for `self.view`. So the `actionHiddenButton` is not in the frame.Its better to have the `controls` you want to animate in the separate view.
 
If you want to see the problem, after your view get transformed set `clipsToBounds` to `YES`. Like

```
    self.view.transform = translation;
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Ok, I got what problem is. What is solution for this then?

Comment: better place the buttons in `UIView`. Then do `CGAffineTransform` for that view